# Why does Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ö") return a 63 '?'?

Tags: .net, encoding, ascii

The `o` umlaut is `148 'ö'` in ASCII, so why does

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ö")
```

return

```
63 '?'
```

?

Comment: There is no 148 is ASCII. ASCII is 7-bit.

Comment: ASCII does not have any values greater than 127 - you possibly might be thinking of the Windows-1252 character encoding?

Comment: The question this is marked a duplicate of doesn't ask quite the same question, and, so, doesn't have a complete answer for part of what you asked: Why "?". The answer is the Encoding.ASCII class has its [EncoderFallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.encoderfallback(v=vs.110).aspx) set to a EncoderReplacementFallback instance with "?" as the replacement character. You are free to create a similar Encoding with a different EncoderFallback behavior, such as an throwing an exception. I usually prefer to fail than to corrupt text.